# Delete google calendar event from Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am running a script under Outlook whereby when I add an event I execute code which adds the event to a google calendar.  I have this code working with Oauth2.0 in place.  When I add the event, I pass the event ID to google so the events in the outlook calendar and the google calendar will have the same event ID.

The next thing I need to do is have the ability to delete the google calendar event when the outlook calendar event is deleted.  I am trying to follow the example from the Google Calendar for Developers (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/delete#auth). I am executing the following code:

```
Private Sub DeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Set httpCall = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<my calendarid>/events/" + Item.EntryID
    httpCall.Open "DELETE", sURL, False
    httpCall.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    httpCall.Send Json
    Dim sReturn As String
    sReturn = httpCall.responseText
    MsgBox (sReturn)
End Sub
```

The message box that gets displayed says Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credentials.  So, I changed the sURL to this:

```
sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<my calendarid>/events/" + Item.EntryID + "?access_token=<my access token>"
```

but now I get this error back: code: 404, message "Not Found"

How do I authenticate a delete request via OAuth2.0 via the google calendar API?

Thank you for any assistance.

I have code which will pass the event ID to the google calendar API but it is failing telling me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to retrieve a valid access token for making such calls. In the string there is a placeholder which should be replaced with a valid value:

```
<my access token>
```

Also you need replace another placeholder in the string with a valid calendar ID:

```
<my calendarid>
```

The `Item.EntryID` value is specific to the local store and may not correspond to the ID on the google calendar. Moreover, the `EntryID` property value can be changed when items are moved to another folder/store. So, I'd suggest using your own IDs instead, so in Outlook you can add a user property to items.

You can read more about calling any Google APIs in the [Google Drive API Using Excel VBA](https://medium.com/coalmont/google-drive-api-using-excel-vba-80e3d7e41488) article where authentication is covered as well.

Comment: I have an access token which I use when I add events to the calendar. I just didnt want to show that access token in this post.  Same for <my calendarid> I use the same calendar id that I use to add items.  As I stated, the add items works.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler then? What do you see there?

Comment: no.  I dont know what Fiddler is. I will look into it but regardless, there must be a way for me to call the API with a DELETE (instead of a POST) and the access key